# How to maintain a list of N most recent viewed items per user in a relational database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like to keep track of the last *n* items that a user has viewed in a PostgreSQL database. My first thought is to create a table such as

```
CREATE TABLE history (
  id            SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id       integer REFERENCES users (id),
  item_id       integer REFERENCES items (id),
  view_date     timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
```

When a user views an object, a new row in the `history` table will record this view. But I only need to maintain the last *n* views for each user, and this approach will store every view that ever occurs.

Is there an efficient way to periodically drop all users' entries that are in excess of their *n* most recent?

EDIT: If there's a better way to store this data than using a SQL table, I'd be interested to hear about that.

Comment: Do you need to store that each time the select? Could you create a data structure in memory and load/save at the start/end of the user's session.

Comment: How about, along with each INSERT, if COUNT > n, DELETE oldest?

Comment: Perhaps adding and maintaining a view_order column would help, if this MUST lie in SQL? @AdmiralAdama 's suggestion would be better from a read/write perspective.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama most likely I'll store the timestamp each time an object is selected (unless the overhead makes this infeasible). I'm providing access to the data through a sessionless API.

Comment: @nate what would you suggest as an alternative to store this information?

Comment: A buffer external to SQL would be ideal. Start storing info on the instantiation of a user's session, keep the most recent n records in the buffer, and dump to SQL when the session is terminated. SQL databases are good for long-term storage, but less so for frequent ops - ESPECIALLY as the database grows larger.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from history
where id in (
    select id
    from (
        select
            id,
            row_number() over(
                partition by user_id
                order by view_date desc
            ) as rn
        from history
    ) s
    where rn > n
)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an efficient way to periodically drop all users' entries that are in excess of their n most recent?

Set up a job that groups, orders and drops every ten minutes or so. You aren't going to find a lot of room for improvement in that sort of query.

From a design perspective though I would favor creating an in memory data structure which you load/save at the start/end of the user's session. That way you don't beat up your database with this sort of work. *But your requirements may make this strategy impossible.*

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> If there's a better way to store this data than using a SQL table, I'd
>   be interested to hear about that.

Database is for persistence of values / object states in a fairly long period of time. If you need frequent access / update of the most recent items, use a cache.

You can listen to the cache notification, when the list expires or is evicted, capture , serialize and save it to database.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808091(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808091%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)